# question about opening a new activity from notification from current activity

Tags: android

My current activity is MyActivity( used to display the data on the list ) and I am getting a new notification. What I am expecting is the data on the list will be refresh when clicking on the notification but It does work that way....There is also a picture of a issue. Any ideas are welcome. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if your problem is ...

clicking the notification opens a **new activity** every time them you have to set the activity **launchMode** as below

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity" android:launchMode="singleTop">
    <meta-data ...
</activity>
```

and handle the notification intent as below

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    handleIntent(getIntent())
}
```

...

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {    
    super.onNewIntent(intent);

    handleIntent(getIntent())
}
```

...

```
private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {

    //Refresh your list here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use 
**listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();** onResume function of Activity, so when you come again on activity, your List show you updated data.

Comment: my problem is I am calling another activity from notification ( not from another activity )... The message is shown from the logcat is

"Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cmp=com.raptureedge.asker/.ReplyActivity bnds=[0,152][480,248] (has extras) }
W/ActivityManager(   66): 
startActivity called from non-Activity context; forcing Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK for: Intent"

Comment: @tonytran Have you solved that problem? I also have this "forcing Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK" message. This is really frustrating